# Out of memory with Entity Framework in a migration process- C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, out-of-memory, database-migration

I am doing a migration process that has to copy all information from one database to another one. When it starts to run all seems good, the problem was when the process reach a complex table.

This table is special because there is some enitities that dependes on it. I'm going to explain it better with an example:

- entityX is a person.
- entityX can have entityY(id account)
- entityX can have a lof of entityZ(friends)
- entityX can have  a lot of entityV(addresses)
- entityX can have a lot of entityW(cars)

The out of memory exception appears when the process has inserted 1159 entityX with its dependencies, more less.

After each entityX we use a function call CleanMemory that uses the GarbageCollector to clean memory.

Any solution to this issue?

```
public static void LoadExample(origin agmCtx, destinity.AgroPelayoEntities agpCtx)
    {//GET ALL THE INFO THAT WE NEED 
        List<EntityX> listOriginX = agmCtx.EntityX.AsNoTracking().ToList();

        foreach (EntityX  ent in list)
        {

            ///LISTS INSERTS//////
            List<destinityEntityX> listInsert = new List<destinity.EntityX>();
            List<destinity.EntityY> listInsertY = new List<destinity.EntityY>();
            List<destinity.EntityZ> listInsertZ = new List<destinity.EntityZ>();
            List<destinity.EntityV> listInsertV = new List<destinity.EntityV>();
            List<destinity.EntityW> listInsertW = new List<destinity.EntityW>();

            ///LISTS UPDATES//////
            List<destinity.EntityX> listUpdate = new List<destinity.EntityX>();

                Boolean exists = listOriginX.Any(e => (e.n_id == ent.n_id));
                if (!exists)
                {
                    //HERE GOES CODE TO CREATE NEW ENTITY AND HIS CHILD(EntityY,List<listInsertZ>, List<EntityV>....)
                    listInsertY.Add(newEntityW);
                    listInsertY.Add(newEntityV);
                    listInsertY.Add(newEntityZ);
                    listInsertY.Add(newEntityY);
                    listInsert.Add(newEntityX);
                }
                else
                {
                    //MODIFY TO HAVE NEW INFO

                    listUpdateV.Add(oldEntityV_Modified);


                }

                int batchSizeX = ClassCommonFuncts.GetNumBatchCount(listInsert.Count());
                int batchSizeY= ClassCommonFuncts.GetNumBatchCount(listInsertY.Count());
                int batchSizeZ = ClassCommonFuncts.GetNumBatchCount(listInsertZ.Count());
                int batchSizeV = ClassCommonFuncts.GetNumBatchCount(listInsertV.Count());
                int batchSizeW = ClassCommonFuncts.GetNumBatchCount(listInsertW.Count());

                int batchSizeUpdateX = ClassCommonFuncts.GetNumBatchCount(listUpdateV.Count());


                agpCtx.BulkInsert<destinity.EntityW>(listInsertW, bulk => bulk.BatchSize = batchSizeW);
                agpCtx.BulkInsert<destinity.EntityV>(listInsertV, bulk => bulk.BatchSize = batchSizeV);
                agpCtx.BulkInsert<destinity.EntityZ>(listInsertZ, bulk => bulk.BatchSize = batchSizeZ);
                agpCtx.BulkInsert<destinity.EntityY>(listInsertY, bulk => bulk.BatchSize = batchSizeY);
                agpCtx.BulkInsert<destinity.EntityX>(listInsert, bulk => bulk.BatchSize = batchSizeX);

                agpCtx.BulkUpdate<destinity.EntityX>(listUpdate, bulk => bulk.BatchSize = batchSizeUpdateX);

                ClassCommonFuncts.CleanMemory();


        }


    }
```

Function CleanMemory

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr process, int minimumWorkingSetSize, int maximumWorkingSetSize);
        public static void CleanMemory()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
        }
```

Function GetNumBatchCount

```
public static int GetNumBatchCount(decimal records)
        {
            if (records > 1000000)
            {
                return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)records / 1000);
            }
            else if (records > 500000)
            {
                return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)records / 100);
            }
            else if (records > 100000)
            {
                return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)records / 50);
            }
            else if (records > 5000)
            {
                return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)records  / 10);
            }
            else
            {
                return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)records / 1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you're calling the garbage collector manually you're doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Why are you adding every item by hand? Why not just `entityX.ListOfEntitiesY = new List<entityY>()`?

Comment: @mjwills I edit my post with the CleanMemory function. In the task manager, migration app use between 80 and 200 mb of the memory . It's so strange..

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I can't response you, I think this was the best way to code it ;)

Comment: It is hardly the best way if you have to keep two references for each item in each list, don't you think?

Comment: First of all, if you correctly set the entire hierarchy of entities (assign entityY, entityZ, entityV and EntityW), then you shouldn't need to bulk insert the entities separately. Each bulk insert is rather memory-expensive operation, so reducing the calls to it should help.
Plus, I support what @Equalsk said about garbage collecting manually.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i think that works if tables EntityX and EntityY were relation in SQL, the problem is that the relation is made with id not with relationships... but the SQL model destiny is created by the client and working in production.

Comment: @Equalsk which is the way doing manually?

Comment: @JakubJankowski I can try to remove bulk in this entity, but in another entities has worked with about 250k records saved, is that what i can't understand :(.

Comment: @kartGIS maybe those entites were smaller ones and the bulk insert worked OK for them. Have you tried different batch sizes?

Comment: @JakubJankowski The function GetNumBatchCount say to the process what is the batch size right. I edit my post to add it ;). Respect to the entity's size, they are similar although X has one more "relation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was "simple". The problem is EntityY has a relation with another entity (1 to n), then when app run over 1000 EntityX crash throwing OutOfMemory Exception.

I fixed it, loading them in small groups, for example grouping by age and male. (In my case I did another group)

Answer (score 0):

Not long term solution. First try to set capacity for your Lists.

Also its a bad practice to call GC in place where you did.

One more thing. Making new lists in every iteration is bad practice and in code like this memory leak is expected.

Comment: I can't understand why I have to set capacity in c# / What is the best practice the to call GC? / It is possible to leak memory but to get an outOfMemory exception... it 's weird isn' it?

Comment: Well that's another topic but lets try to explain. For capacity of list you need to know how list are implement in c#. They are arrays in background, and they init capacity is 0. After first add capacity is 4.When you add 5 elements capacity is 8 (and old one stay in memory resulting memory leak).
Form MSDN:
"If Count exceeds Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old elements and adding the new elements."